# Function wcwidth not found - python

Tags: python, ansible, cygwin

I installed wcwidth through pip on cygwin but I get this error when I try to run Ansible-playbook  binary through powershell.
Ansible-playbook binary works fine from cygwin but doesn't work from powershell

```
PS C:\> c:\cywing\bin\bash.exe /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/ansible-playbook", line 64, in <module>
    from ansible.utils.display import Display, initialize_locale
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/utils/display.py", line 55, in <module>
    _LIBC.wcwidth.argtypes = (ctypes.c_wchar,)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 379, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 384, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'wcwidth' not found
```

Comment: Is this in a virtualenv or not? And is `wcwidth` installed in the virtualenv?

Comment: What does *c:\cywing\bin\bash.exe* output?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce the exact behavior, since I don't have *Ansible* installed in the *Cygwin* environment. When I tried installing it, I got some errors (building some dependencies), and I didn't feel like investigating further. So I tried creating my own "*MCVE*", but I ran into all sorts of problems.

*script00.sh*:

```bash
printf -- "CWD: %s\n\${PATH}: %s\n" "$(pwd)" "${PATH}"

./code00.py
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os 
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.util as cutil


def main(*argv):
    print("OS name: ", os.name)
    print("ctypes module:", ct)

    c_path = cutil.find_library("c")
    if not c_path:
        print("!!! libc not found !!!")
        return 1
    print("libc path:", c_path)
    lc = ct.CDLL(c_path)

    wcw = lc.wcwidth
    print("wcwidth:", wcw)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output** (I'll be reusing the same console in multiple snippets):

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q068647743]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\Cygwin\Cygwin\Version\bin\bash.exe" script00.sh
> CWD: /cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q068647743
> ${PATH}: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/dotnet:/cygdrive/c/Install/pc064/Docker/Docker/Version/Docker/resources/bin:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/Utils/current/Win:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_pc064_03.08.07_test0/Scripts:/cygdrive/c/Users/cfati/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/cygdrive/c/Users/cfati/.dotnet/tools
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> OS name:  nt
> ctypes module: <module 'ctypes' from 'c:\\Install\\pc064\\Python\\Python\\03.08.07\\lib\\ctypes\\__init__.py'>
> !!! libc not found !!!
>
> Done.
> ```

As seen, it launches some *Python*, but **it's a *Win* one** (notice the paths), which should not happen. The reason is that my *Win* *%PATH%* contains its *dir*.

> ```bat
> [prompt]> echo %PATH%
> C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Install\pc064\Docker\Docker\Version\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\cfati\.dotnet\tools
>
> [prompt]> :: Remove all Pythons from %PATH%
> [prompt]> set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Install\pc064\Docker\Docker\Version\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;C:\Users\cfati\.dotnet\tools
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\Cygwin\Cygwin\Version\bin\bash.exe" script00.sh
> CWD: /cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q068647743
> ${PATH}: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/dotnet:/cygdrive/c/Install/pc064/Docker/Docker/Version/Docker/resources/bin:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/Utils/current/Win:/cygdrive/c/Users/cfati/.dotnet/tools
> /usr/bin/env: 'python': No such file or directory
> ```

One thing that arises is that no *Nix* style path (*/usr/bin*) is present in *${PATH}*. That is because they are added (if some *env* *var*s are set) by ***/etc/profile*, which only gets executed by login shells**.

That was the **WHY** part.

**Solutions**:

1. **Use the *Cygwin* console (*Mintty*)**. *Cygwin* *app*s were meant to run inside a certain environment, the fact they work outside, is a pure coincidence (luck). Any other approach would be a (more or less lame) workaround
2. Let *Bash* load all the initialization files (*profile*, *bashrc*, ...). Closest as it was launched from *Mintty*:

   > ```bat
   > [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\Cygwin\Cygwin\Version\bin\bash.exe" -l -c "cd \"%CD%\"; ./script00.sh"
   > CWD: /cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q068647743
   > ${PATH}: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/dotnet:/cygdrive/c/Install/pc064/Docker/Docker/Version/Docker/resources/bin:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/Utils/current/Win:/cygdrive/c/Users/cfati/.dotnet/tools
   > Python 3.8.10 (default, May 20 2021, 11:41:59) [GCC 10.2.0] 064bit on cygwin
   >
   > OS name:  posix
   > ctypes module: <module 'ctypes' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py'>
   > libc path: cygwin1.dll
   > wcwidth: <_FuncPtr object at 0x6fffffe96280>
   > Done.
   > ```
3. Launch *Bash* with some system paths (*/usr/local/bin*, */usr/bin*) added to *${PATH}* ([[SO]: Function wcwidth not found - python (@John's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68647743/function-wcwidth-not-found-python/68661198#68661198)). Although it does the trick for this case, it's **not at all generic**. Note that some other variables (*LD_LIBRARY_PATH*) might need adjustments as well, so it might be an overkill

   - As a variant, the corresponding paths (***Win* style**) could be added to *%PATH%*, before starting *Bash*
4. There are more (variations), but they don't worth to be mentioned

**Final note**: *Cygwin* is kind of obsolete. Switch to *WSL(**2**)*, which runs a real *Ubuntu* (no wrappers / adapters) as a *VM* (in *Hyper-V* - which runs at a totally different level).

Answer (score -1):

Figured out the issue.. I had to export PATH variable

```
c:\cywing\bin\bash.exe -c "export PATH='/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin' && /usr/bin/ansible-playbook test.yml"
```